# Sublime text Hexadecimal View

Tags: html, sublimetext

How can I get back to text version from hexadecimal in sublime text?

I accidentally changed the encoding of my .css file to Hexadecimal in sublime text.

How can I get back the normal text .css?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Files containing null bytes are opened as hexadecimal by default In your User or Default Settings file:

```
"enable_hexadecimal_encoding": false
```

**OR**

In your User or Default Settings file(s):

```
"preview_on_click": false
```

Answer (score 114):

Go to **`File -> Reopen with Encoding`** and select **`UTF-8`**. This will bring back the normal text view.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the votes also suggest.

Comment: @RobertoLoGiacco Not necessarily.  I tried this on my 1.7 Gigabyte file and it did nothing but spin till I killed it 10 minutes later.  However, when I overrode the enable_hexadecimal_encoding setting as mentioned above, it opened the file as text in under 30 seconds.  So, for large files, override the defaults and for smaller files this answer is probably more correct.

Comment: A 1.7 GB of CSS? I mean, I understand a log or data file that size, in which case yes, I agree, the Reopen with encoding is definitely not the way, but the OP was referring to what I would call "a normal size text file".

Comment: This is a handy way to fix viewing files containing null bytes without actually altering the default settings.  Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 7):

Are you perhaps using Hex Viewer plugin?

Try hitting Ctrl+shift+p (command pallette) and Toggle Hex View

Comment: Also accessible from Tools -> Packages -> HexViewer

Answer (score 3):

In the sublime i have, which is version 3, Reopen with Encoding has an hexadecimal option. !!